# Android contentprovideroperations insert or update

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have implemented own contentprovider for android app. I am using contentprovideroperations for batch processing. I would like to have operation similar to PUT in web request where if an entry is present then it gets updated and if its not present then it gets inserted (similar to POST request). There are separate methods for newInsert and newUpdate in contentprovideroperations.

One way is to first update and check if entry is present and if its not then insert new element. But since I am adding all operations in batch for processing them together later, I cannot do that. So I need a single line operation that does insert/update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a temporary workable fix that I will always user newInsert operation along with on conflict replace in sqlite for primary key.

```
"PRIMARY KEY("id") ON CONFLICT REPLACE"
```

So If I have a new entry to add, it will as per the usage of newInsert add that entry and if primary key "id" is already present then it will replace the old entry with new one.